# Why is the instance piped name empty in my LocalDB configuration?

Tags: localdb

I wanted to connect to my LocalDB through jTDS. In the connection string the `Data Source` is `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`. I discovered that I need the instance piped name to connect to the db, so I ran `sqllocaldb i mssqllocaldb` but the instance piped name is empty.

What can I do to connect?

Comment: Try `(localdb)`

Comment: It does not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance piped name was empty simply because is was not running, I went in visual studio and then it showed me the piped name